# How to use where method with null boolean

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list like this:

```
[
    {'country': ' Wakanda', 'languages': null},
    {
      'country': 'USA',
      'languages': [
        {'language': 'English'}
      ]
    },
    {
      'country': 'Germany',
      'languages': [
        {'language': 'German'}
      ]
    },
    {
      'country': ' Ireland',
      'languages': [
        {'language': 'English'},
        {'language': 'Irish'}
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I try to create a new list that 'language' contains 'eng'`toLowwerCase()`, but the error is `Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null`
So pls help me, this is the full code:

```
void main() async {
  List list = [
    {'country': ' Wakanda', 'languages': null},
    {
      'country': 'USA',
      'languages': [
        {'language': 'English'}
      ]
    },
    {
      'country': 'Germany',
      'languages': [
        {'language': 'German'}
      ]
    },
    {
      'country': ' Ireland',
      'languages': [
        {'language': 'English'},
        {'language': 'Irish'}
      ]
    }
  ];

  List filterList = List.from(list).where((e) {
    return e['languages']?.any((l) => l['language'].toLowwerCase().contains('eng').toLowwerCase());
  }).toList();

  print(filterList);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback to `Iterable.where` must return a non-nullable `bool` type.  Your callback potentially returns `null` if `e['languages']` returns `null`:

```dart
return e['languages']?.any(
  (l) => l['language'].toLowwerCase().contains('eng').toLowwerCase()
);
```

The way to fix it is to handle `null`.  You can use `x ?? y` to provide a default value of `y` if `x` is `null`:

```dart
return e['languages']?.any(
  (l) => l['language'].toLowwerCase().contains('eng').toLowwerCase()
) ?? false;
```

I'll also point out that:

- `toLowerCase()` is misspelled.
- `List.from(list).where(...).toList()` is redundant and could be just `list.where(...).toList()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
  List filterList = List.from(list).where((e) {
    // Avoid check null valúes
    if (e['languages'] == null) {
      return false;
    }

    return e['languages']?.any(
        (l) => l['language'].toLowwerCase().contains('eng').toLowwerCase());
  }).toList();
```

Also you can validate language child value

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() async {
 List list = [
  {'country': ' Wakanda', 'languages': null},
   {
     'country': 'USA',
     'languages': [
        {'language': 'English'}
      ]
   },
   {
     'country': 'Germany',
     'languages': [
       {'language': 'German'}
      ]
    },
   {
     'country': ' Ireland',
     'languages': [
       {'language': 'English'},
       {'language': 'Irish'}
     ]
    }
   ];

   List filterList = List.from(list).where((e) {
   try{
      return e['languages']?.any((l) => 
         l['language'].toLowwerCase().contains('eng').toLowwerCase());
      }).toList();
   }
   catch(e){
       return [''];
   }
   print(filterList);
 }
```